# Use wget command in Silex?

Tags: exec, silex

I've been trying to use exec with Silex but my commands aren't executing. 
Actually I need to retrieve an entire website along with it's css, js and images and store it in a directory in my server.

```
exec("wget \
                --recursive \
                --no-clobber \
                --page-requisites \
                --html-extension \
                --convert-links \
                --restrict-file-names=windows \
                --domains website.org \
                --no-parent \
                    www.website.org/tutorials/html/");
```

I've been told not to use exec() with Silex, so can you please help me out guys?

Comment: How are you trying to execute your command? And who told you not to use ```exec``` *in* Silex and why?

Comment: Umm I just put the code above in a function and running it. But it isn't outputting or doing anything.
I read somewhere in stackoverflow itself that it isn't a good practice to use exec within silex.

Comment: Do you have php errors enabled? Are you running this from command line, I guess, any output so far?

Comment: yes php errors are enabled but no output!

Comment: Some environments disable some functions by the use of [*disable_functions*](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) php ini config key, make sure your PHP is allowed to call the ```exec``` function.

Comment: yes i just checked, exec is not disabled.

Comment: does the wget command work on shell on the same machine? you also could try to echo the outputs: exec("wget ...", $out); var_dump($out);

Comment: I tried `exec("wget -m http://ginatrapani.googlepages.com", $out);` `var_dump($out);`
I got this output `array(0) { }`

Comment: Ps. I'm running a windows machine, so I guess I can't run `wget` directly on the shell

Comment: you must be able to run the wget command on shell/console on your machine, if you cant your php script cant either

Answer (score 0):

You can make wget as a commandline utility inside Windows shell by installing chocolatey package manager and then wget.

In order to install the package manager run this inside a Console with Administrator privileges:
`@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin`

Then you can install wget and make it available in your shell (therefore PHP):
`choco install -y wget` (don't forget run this inside a privileged console).

Comment: Thanks I will try it and report back asap.
But my main concern is; what about when I put my website online, the server won't be able to run the `exec()` or `wget` command!

Comment: You could try exec('PATH') FROM your php script to know if the path where is located the wget binary, is available to the user account running your site/scripts. If it is not, you can add the path to the system PATH variable.